# Scapy - Non-existent attribute / field returning a value

Tags: python, scapy

I've been coding my own protocol in `Scapy` and have had issues calculating length fields ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413822/scapy-variable-length-field-covering-multiple-fields)). Another issue I've run into with my bitfield defined length layers is that if I call to return the length field in a layer which it isn't defined, it will return a value.  If I call `hasattr(pckt[layer], 'field')`, it will return 'true', which states the attribute / field exists.  This doesn't make any sense to me as the layer definition is shown below:

```
class Layer(Packet):
   name = "Layer"
   fields_desc = [ BitField("Padding", 15, 4),
           BitField("Digit", 0, 4) ]
```

As you can see, the only attributes / fields defined are `Padding` and `Digit`.  `Length` is not defined, so why is `Scapy` returning an integer and `true` for the two calls I am performing?

Comment: The relationship of `hasattr(pckt[layer], 'field')` to your question is unclear.  Please show code that reproduces the problem, using a complete packet

Comment: @MikePennington I'm apologize I thought I was clear with that comment. The reason I included hasattr() is to show that Scapy thinks there's a layer defined when there actually isn't.  So in the code I provided, if I were to call hasattr(pckt[Layer], 'Padding') or hasattr(pckt[Layer], 'Random'), both would return true even though the only layer that exists is Padding.  Thank you for your reply btw! Much appreciated.